# How to defer an anonymous function returned by a function

Tags: go, defer-keyword

Let’s say you have a function that sets up your application server and returns a function that should be run right before your application exits.

```
func main() {
  defer applicationExit()
}

func applicationExit() func() {
  fmt.Println(" Application Setup Call")

  return func() {
    fmt.Println("Application Tear Down Call")
  }
}
```

You will get the following output.
`Output: Application Setup Call`

What went wrong? Why don’t we see the output `Application Tear Down Call`

Comment: `defer` only evaluates the call and its arguments, to allocate the state, it does not actually execute the call, the call gets executed only when the outer function exists and anything that that call returns gets discarded.

Comment: Also note that while it may not be working *as **you** expect*, it is actually working *properly* as defined by the spec.

Comment: If you want the output of the last func you can do this: https://play.golang.com/p/X72RCtw7BOd however this will print out the first line before the function exits, it will not be deferred.

Answer (score 5):

Your code does exactly what is expected:

```
func main() {
    defer applicationExit()
}
```

Translated to English, this code means:

> - Wait until `main` exits, then call `applicationExit()`.

This is what happens. But what you seem to want is, instead:

> - Execute `applicationExit()` immediately, and store the return value for later.
> - Wait until application exits, then call the anonymous function returned by `applicationExit()`.

If we write this *actual* code, we get something like:

```
func main() {
    cleanup := applicationExit() // Call applicationExit() immediately
    defer cleanup() // Wait until main() exits, then call cleanup()
}
```

which can be shortened to:

```
func main() {
    defer applicationExit()()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to invoke the function that is returned. **applicationExit()** just returns the function and does nothing else. To execute it you have to invoke the function.

```
func main() {
  defer applicationExit()()
}

func applicationExit() func() {
  fmt.Println(" Application Setup Call")

  return func() {
    fmt.Println("Application Tear Down Call")
  }
}
```